# techniques to make/making a safe tackle

Tags: grammar

In this [NPR news excerpt](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=311254823), it says

> They can easily talk about these steps and techniques to **making** a safe tackle.

It is wrong and should be **make** right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Making* is fine here.

Mr. Jackson is using the preposition *to*, not the infinitive marker *to*.

He is not employing an ‘infinitive of purpose’ and speaking about how steps and techniques are performed *in order to* make a safe tackle.

Rather, he is speaking about the steps and techniques which are *involved in* making a safe tackle. Use of *to* in this sense is common in conversational English (note that Mr. Jackson is not reading from a script but speaking off the cuff). And it is not unknown in more formal contexts:

> There is a certain art to saying ‘no’ tactfully.
>   The steps to constructing the Load Chart are as follows ...
>   There is a special technique to writing television, a special craft ...

Comment: You mean both "steps to write/writing" "technique to write/writing" are fine? With only slightly different meanings(in order to or involved in)?

Comment: @CYC Well, the only important "step" to writing I know of is to stop staring at the blank screen and write, but, basically, Yeah.